# Android: How to add Pre-loaded Application?

Tags: android, kernel

I have been trying to make my application a pre-loaded application on the Android OS Kernel. Within these two makefiles: `generic.mk` and `core.mk`, I added my application to the list of pre-loaded applications found under `PRODUCT_PACKAGES:=`, but when I load my custom kernel my application is not installed. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by flashing the `system.img` along with the `boot.img`